# Encode php files in UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: php, file, utf-8, fwrite

How to write files in UTF-8 without BOM ?

The special character text comes i.e. from a translation in another language using Google Translate.

edit-start:
Since i was asked how this variable is written.

```
$file_content = "/** some comments **/";
$file_content .= utf8_encode("\n\n// $lang = array_merge($lang, array('Trans_leave_orig'                => 'Dacă nu este tradus text <b> lăsaţi original </br>',)) \n\n");
$file_content .= "/** some more comments **/";
```

edit-ends.
I have something like this:

```
$file_save_content = "<" . "?php\n" . $file_content . "\n\n//\n// File Ends. \n// -------------------------------------------------\n?" . ">";
```

Putting a BOM before will work but file content is not saved in utf-8 and so we have ?? for every special character:

```
$file_save_content = "\xEF\xBB\xBF<" . "?php\n" . $file_content . "\n\n//\n// File Ends. \n// -------------------------------------------------\n?" . ">";
```

edit-start:

```
$fp = fopen( $file_save_path, 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, $file_save_content); 
fclose($fp);
```

edit-ends.

Comment: which method are you using to save this with, and what are the source files' encoding themselves?

Comment: also, what is `$file_content`'s source and content values?

Comment: can you (please) add that to your post by editing it? and what the data looks like from the source you're getting this from, or a short similar example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51690674/edit < use that to edit your post. Please don't drop code in comments, we can't work with that. There is also an "edit" button/link underneath your question and over to the left.

Comment: I added the comments with code in the post.